# Hibernate - Mapping: Could not determine type for #, at table: #, for columns: #

Tags: java, database, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I tried everything, but I'm stuck. 
Can you help me please?

The small project is just a preliminary test for a large database. I've only been using Hibernate for a week and I'm trying to connect it all with Srping MVC Tomcat later.

But now I just want to be able to recognize the mistakes in the mapping.

**Console:**

```
    `Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: hiber.data_examplecompany.Address, at table: EMPLOYEE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(address)]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tools.hiber.HiberUtil.<clinit>(HiberUtil.java:19)
    at tools.hiber.HiberSave.main(HiberSave.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: hiber.data_examplecompany.Address, at table: EMPLOYEE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(address)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at tools.hiber.HiberUtil.<clinit>(HiberUtil.java:15)
    ... 1 more
```

**Employee.java:**

```
package hiber.data_examplecompany;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "emp_salary")
    private double salary;

    private Address address;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Employee getName called");
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Employee setName called");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "emp_salary")
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id= " + id + ", Name= " + name + ", Salary= " + salary
                + ", {Address= " + address + "}";
    }

}
```

**Address.java:**

```
package hiber.data_examplecompany;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "property", value = "employee") })
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "address_line1")
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipcode;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Employee employee;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressLine1= " + addressLine1 + ", City=" + city
                + ", Zipcode=" + zipcode;
    }
}
```

**Thank you
for the time invested! :)**

Comment: You miss the Annotation about `private Address address;`. Think it must `@oneToOne(....)`

Comment: See https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your mapping is ok. Each Employee could have one Address. But you did small mistake i think. As my knowledge Whenever creating tables in hibernate using annotation use all annotation at one place i mean Field or property level. Basically, Hibernate will look to other required annotation based on @Id annotation position. So in your case @Id is in field level and @OneToOne is on property level in Employee table. Please do the same changes and try again, let me know.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "emp_salary")
    private double salary;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
    private Address address;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Employee getName called");
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Employee setName called");
        this.name = name;
    }


    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id= " + id + ", Name= " + name + ", Salary= " + salary
                + ", {Address= " + address + "}";
    }
```

Comment: @AngardBansode
Thank you so much! it worked.
However, I now get a SQL error ..

` Sep 07, 2018 2:28:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
Sep 07, 2018 2:28:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Field 'emp_id' doesn't have a default value `

and also a "could not execute statement" error caused by the SQL

Comment: If this solution helps, Could you please accept this solution and upvote.